# Airflow retain the same database connection?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow for some ETL things and in some stages, I would like to use temporary tables (mostly to keep the code and data objects self-contained and to avoid to use a lot of metadata tables).

Using the Postgres connection in Airflow and the "PostgresOperator" the behaviour that I found was: For **each execution of a PostgresOperator we have a new connection (or session, you name it) in the database**. In other words: We lose all temporary objects of the previous component of the DAG.

To emulate a simple example, I use this code (do not run, just see the objects):

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow'
    ,'depends_on_past': False
    ,'start_date': datetime(2018, 6, 13)
    ,'retries': 3
    ,'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'refresh_views'
    , default_args=default_args)

# Create database workflow
drop_exist_temporary_view = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary_table_to_be_used;"

create_temporary_view = """
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table_to_be_used AS 
SELECT relname AS views
       ,CASE WHEN relispopulated = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS relispopulated
       ,CAST(reltuples AS INT) AS reltuples
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relname = 'some_view'
ORDER BY reltuples ASC;"""

use_temporary_view = """
DO $$
DECLARE
  is_correct integer := (SELECT relispopulated FROM temporary_table_to_be_used WHERE views LIKE '%<<some_name>>%');
BEGIN

start_time := clock_timestamp();
    IF is_materialized = 0 THEN
       EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || view_to_refresh || ' WITH DATA;';
    ELSE 
       EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY ' || view_to_refresh || ' WITH DATA;';
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
"""

# Objects to be executed
drop_exist_temporary_view = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='drop_exist_temporary_view',
    sql=drop_exist_temporary_view,
    postgres_conn_id='dwh_staging',
    dag=dag)

create_temporary_view = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='create_temporary_view',
    sql=create_temporary_view,
    postgres_conn_id='dwh_staging',
    dag=dag)

use_temporary_view = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='use_temporary_view',
    sql=use_temporary_view,
    postgres_conn_id='dwh_staging',
    dag=dag)

# Data workflow
drop_exist_temporary_view >> create_temporary_view >> use_temporary_view
```

At the end of execution, I receive the following message:

```
[2018-06-14 15:26:44,807] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "temporary_table_to_be_used" does not exist
```

Someone knows if Airflow has some way to retain the same connection to the database? I think it can save a lot of work in creating/maintaining several objects in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retain the connection to the database by building a custom Operator which leverages the PostgresHook to retain a connection to the db while you perform some set of sql operations.

You may find some examples in [contrib on incubator-airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/contrib/operators) or in [Airflow-Plugins](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/).

Another option is to persist this temporary data to [XCOMs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms). This will give you the ability to keep the metadata used with the task in which it was created. This may help troubleshooting down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @andscoop; but I think it should be a property of the connection instead to solve this in some operator that can increase the complexity of the DAG. 

For several cases where you have cases of processing some tables in stages the reuse a temporary table across multiple tasks can be very useful and plus: can remove a lot of pressure in the RDBMS cause you won't need to hit several times

Comment: If you go the first route of building a custom operator you can make it a property of the connection.

The problem is you are attempting to re-use the same connection across multiple tasks, but there is no guarantee in Airflow that different tasks will be run on the same node, due to the distributed nature of Airflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @andscoop.

I'll suggest this for the Airflow team, because I think it is, in some instance, a blocker for the migration some pipelines that uses the same connection. [Data Integration Kettle have the same problem](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/230786-Table-Input-with-Temporary-Table/) and the [SSIS have this on the shelf](http://www.thesqlgoth.com/2015/05/ssis-performance-tip.html).